# How to check if a form is partially filled in or completely empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a couple models: Phone, Email, Person.  I would like to follow a DRY development path, currently I am implementing ModelForms.  (Django 1.6)

I need to be able to accept **two instances of "Person"**, the second is **optional**, and if not present it's associated phone and email forms shouldn't validate.  I also would be able to **accept multiple** phone and email instances, but only **require one of each**.

Pseudo-Schema

```
class Person(modelForm):
     first_name = CharField
     last_name = CharField
     ...

class Phone(modelForm): 
     person_ID = ForeignKey(Person)
     typ = CharField(choices = ...)
     number = CharField

class Email(modelForm): 
     person_ID = ForeignKey(Person)
     typ = CharField(choices = ...)
     email = CharField
```

Pseudo-Form Templete

```
form>
{{Location_Contact}} #<-required
{{Location_Phone_1}} #<-required
{{Location_Phone_2}} #<-optional but if a field is filled in preform validation
{{Location_Email_1}} #<-required

# optional below but if any part is filled in, treat it like the above
{{Billing_Contact}} 
{{Billing_Phone_1}}
{{Billing_Phone_2}}
{{Billing_Email_1}}
/form>
```

I could probably make this work if I could figure out a way to check and see if a form is untouched and partially filled in; but I haven't found a reliable way of doing this.
I am fairly new to Django maybe going about this the wrong way, any pointers would be appreciated, even if it is a complete overhaul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Django built-in Formsets module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). It was designed specifically to support this and similar use cases.

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

PersonFormSet = formset_factory(
    PersonForm,
    extra=2,
    max_num=2,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True
)
```

- `extra=2` means that two empty forms will be displayed.
- `max_num=2` means no more than two forms will ever be displayed (only really makes sense with edit form)
- `min_num=1` together with `validate_min=True` means user is required to fill out at least a single form.

Note that `validate_min` was added in the current dev version and will be avialiable in Django 1.7. In Django up to 1.6 you need to use [custom formset validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Mk, I will look into this tomorrow. Thanks for the tip. (I looked around forever...)

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want, much appreciated. (I actually saw this earlier but glossed over it).